# How to change color border bottom blue line to green green line in select field using react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-design, material-ui

I am using the select field from [material UI react](https://material-ui.com/api/select/)

When I select any item from the field I face two issues:

1. Border bottom line become blue and background color become gray. I need to change Border bottom line to green and background color to white.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/zqok7r3x63

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel
            required
            htmlFor="age-native-simple"
            FormLabelClasses={{
              asterisk: classes.labelAsterisk,
              root: classes.labelRoot,
              focused: classes.focusedLabel
            }}
          >
            Role
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            className=""
            native
            classes={{}}
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange("age")}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-native-simple",
              classes: {
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                focused: classes.inputFocused,
                underline: classes.underlineInput
              }
            }}
          >
            <option value="" disabled />
            <option value={10}>Ten</option>
            <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
            <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

[image: c]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the native Select, there are two main elements in play: an [`Input`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Input/Input.js) and a native `<select>`. The `Input` is what you need to change the underline on, but for a native Select the `inputProps` are passed to the native `select` and not the `Input`. You can customize the `Input` in this case via the `input` property and then provide it with the `underline` class. The background color you are trying to change when focused is for the `select` so that can be passed directly in the `classes` property.

Below are the styles and code for the Select and an updated version of your sandbox. In my example I used three different colors for the underline for the different states so you can easily see the effect, but you can change all/any of these to your preferred shade of green.

```
const styles = {
  focused: {},
  disabled: {},
  error: {},
  select: {
    "&:focus": {
      backgroundColor: "white"
    }
  },
  underlineInput: {
    "&:before": {
      // normal
      borderBottom: "1px solid #00ff00"
    },
    "&:after": {
      // focused
      borderBottom: `2px solid #ff0000`
    },
    "&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error):before": {
      // hover
      borderBottom: `2px solid #0000ff`
    }
  }
};
```

```
          <Select
            native
            classes={{ select: classes.select }}
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange("age")}
            input={
              <Input
                classes={{
                  root: classes.inputRoot,
                  focused: classes.focused,
                  disabled: classes.disabled,
                  error: classes.error,
                  underline: classes.underlineInput
                }}
              />
            }
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-native-simple"
            }}
          >
            <option value="" disabled />
            <option value={10}>Ten</option>
            <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
            <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
          </Select>
```

[image: Edit Native Select custom underline]

Answer (score 0):

First, "Select" material-UI component only accepts root, select, filled, outlined, selectMenu, disabled, and icon on its classes attribute as stated in the docs, so there is no 'focused' and 'underline'.

Second, you can write your custom CSS the way you want and inject it to the appropriate class, for example, to make focused select background white :

change the classes

```
classes: {
            root: classes.inputRoot,
            select: classes.inputFocused
          }
```

change the css

```
  inputFocused: {
    "&:focus": {
    backgroundColor: "white"}
  },
```

hope it helps