# Material-UI 4.1.2 Styling Select SelectInput

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to alter the style of the SelectInput. I'm using a class based component. I set it up this way:

```
const QuoteListStyle = {
  color: "#eceff1",
  borderBottom: "1px solid #90caf9",
  "&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $underline": {
    borderBottom: "2px solid #90caf9"
  },
  width: "196px",
  marginTop: "1rem"
};
```

Then in the render I have this section with the Select:

```
<FormControl>
                    <Select
                      style={QuoteListStyle}
                      value={this.state.quoteListName}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      displayEmpty={true}
                      renderValue={
                        this.state.quoteListName > 0
                          ? undefined
                          : () => <em>{this.state.quoteListName}</em>
                      }
                    >
                      <MenuItem value="" disabled>
                        <em>Select a Quote List</em>
                      </MenuItem>

                      {data.me.quoteList.map(item => {
                        return (
                          <MenuItem value={item.name} key={item.name}>
                            {item.name}
                          </MenuItem>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Select>
                  </FormControl>
```

I'm using the basic Select component that only has an underline. I want to change the color and size of the underline. I looked here in the source:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js

What do I look for to control the underline? 
I am seeing the underline that I want when the component loads. The hover is not working. After an item from the Select is chosen, I see my style on top but the default style is below and I can see some of that color.

I would be ok using overrides for this. Here's my theme code:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#90caf9",
      contrastText: "#f5f5f5"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#19857b"
    },
    error: {
      main: "#f44336"
    },
    background: {
      default: "#102027",
      paper: "#37474f"
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#eceff1",
      secondary: "#90caf9"
    },
    button: {
      borderColor: "#90caf9"
    }
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        "& $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "#90caf9"
        },
        "&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "#90caf9",
          borderWidth: 2
        },
        "&$focused $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "#90caf9"
        }
      },
      notchedOutline: {}
    },
    MuiSelect: {
      icon: {
        fill: "#90caf9"
      }
    }
  }
});

export default theme;
```

I also looked in the devtools and found this:

```
<div class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputSelect" aria-pressed="false" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"><em>Tech</em></div>
```

I'm not sure how to use that to target what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't target other rules or pseudo-classes (e.g. `"&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $underline"`) in inline styles. Instead you need to use CSS classes (e.g. via `makeStyles` for function components or `withStyles` can be used with both class and function components).

The styles you need to customize are within [Input](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Input/Input.js#L27). Below is an example of how to customize the underline.

You can read more about this in my related answers:

- [How do I custom style the underline of Material-UI without using theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023814/how-do-i-custom-style-the-underline-of-material-ui-without-using-theme/56026253#56026253)
- [How to change color border bottom blue line to green green line in select field using react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055047/how-to-change-color-border-bottom-blue-line-to-green-green-line-in-select-field/55055748#55055748)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  select: {
    "&:before": {
      // normal
      borderBottom: "1px solid orange"
    },
    "&:after": {
      // focused
      borderBottom: `3px solid green`
    },
    "&:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):not(.Mui-focused):not(.Mui-error):before": {
      // hover
      borderBottom: `2px solid purple`
    }
  }
});

const App = () => {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <FormControl style={{ minWidth: "200px" }}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          className={classes.select}
          value={age}
          onChange={event => setAge(event.target.value)}
          inputProps={{
            name: "age",
            id: "age-simple"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="" disabled />
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Select custom underline]

Comment: Ah ok Ryan, that is making sense, thank you! I'll work on this.

Comment: Ok, the styles are working but other things are broken. Working on it...

Comment: Yeah I just hit the upvote/check mark, I was focused on getting it working and didn't get it going util this morning. Many thanks!