# Style Select underline

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I'm trying to use style-components to style the underline of a select component.
I sucessfully styled the underline of an Input component.
I'm aware that Select is a wrapper of Input but for some reason the same code does not work for Select.

```
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  && {
    && .MuiInput-underline {
      border-bottom: 2px solid green;
    }
    /* default */
    .MuiInput-underline:before {
      border-bottom: 2px solid green;
    }
    /* hover (double-ampersand needed for specificity reasons. */
    && .MuiInput-underline:hover:before {
      border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
    }
    /* focused */
    .MuiInput-underline:after {
      border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    }
  }
`;

export default StyledSelect;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-underline-styled-components-fe0jk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are targeting the `MuiInput-underline` class as if it is a [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) of the `Select`, but the root div (the one that the `styled-components` class name will be applied to) of the `Select` is the element with the `MuiInput-underline` class.

Below is an example of the correct syntax:

```
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  /* default */
  &.MuiInput-underline:before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  }
  /* hover */
  &.MuiInput-underline:hover:before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
  }
  /* focused */
  &.MuiInput-underline:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  }
`;

export default StyledSelect;
```

[image: Edit TextField underline styled-components]

I also made a change to **index.js** to wrap everything in `<StylesProvider injectFirst>`. This should generally be used when you are using `styled-components` with Material-UI so that the Material-UI styles come first in the `<head>` instead of last. Then the `styled-components` styles will come after the Material-UI styles and win when specificity is otherwise the same. This avoids needing to double up class names (e.g. using `&&`) as much to increase specificity.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Demo from "./demo";
import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

ReactDOM.render(
  <StylesProvider injectFirst>
    <Demo style={{ width: "200px" }} value={1} />
  </StylesProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Related answer: [Material-UI 4.1.2 Styling Select SelectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978010/material-ui-4-1-2-styling-select-selectinput/56978716#56978716)